# Titianim app Ti.Android.currentActivity is undefine

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am new to Titanim Development. Now I am working with a existing app. The app seems to developed with the **3.0.2** version but **I configured my system(OSX maverick) with latest version(3.2.3)**.

**source:**

```
Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(Ti.Android.createIntent({
      url: '/app/ui/WindowEula'
    }));
```

When I build and run the application the application through error in the above line

> Ti.Android.currentActivity is undefine.

How to fix this error.

Comment: may be a issue of Heavyweight and Lightweight Windows , please check at [titanium doc](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window)

Comment: @sumit I am not clear what you actually saying when check the with the document they said latest version uses only heavyweight window.But I am not sure what I have to do. One more just now I check Its running in android only not working ios

Comment: Is this an alloy app? If so the `app` folder will not exist after the alloy pre-compile. Try `url : 'ui/WindowEula'`

Comment: I dont think so. My source is working in Android only problem exist in Ios device. Whether we need any platform specific code to run.

Comment: @CoolMonster , actually the activity code will work for only android , its platform specific. U can detect the platform as `if(Ti.Platform.osname === "android") `

Comment: @sumit whether the code Ti.Android will only work on Android or else its common for all platform.

Comment: @CoolMonster , if you use Ti.Android in iOS you will always get an error , because this API or method is only for Android platform.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
var activity = Titanium.Android.currentActivity;
activity.finish();
```

use `currentActivity` instead of `CurrentActivity`.

Comment: I am using currentActivity only not CurrentActivity sorry misspelled. Can you see my updated question. With code where it cause the problem